# how do I pass a query within a spring mvc controller?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

assume you have something like this in normal servlet without using spring mvc:

```
if(username == "X" && password =="Y"){
  response.sendRedirect("./user/welcomePage.jsp");
}else{
  response.sendRedirect("./login.jsp?wrongPass=true");
 }
```

and if the username && password is wrong, after redirection to login.jsp page, inform user that the username or password is wrong, somewhere in the login.jsp page in red color:

```
<p style="color:red";
 <%= (request.getParameter("wrongPass")==null)? "visibility:hidden":"" %>;">
    Your username/password is wrong !</p>
```

My question is, is there any way to pass an argument like:

```
response.sendRedirect("./login.jsp?wrongPass=true");
```

inside Spring MVC controller ?

coz if we have a controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ="/")
public class Welcome{
public String welcome(@RequestParam("j_username") String username, 
        @RequestParam("j_password") String password){
       .
       .
       .
   return "login";
```

as log as we need to return a String to form a page & because we have InternalResourceViewResolver defined:

```
<bean >class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

if we pass the argument in our controller like: return "login?wrongPass=true"
after using InternalResourceViewResolver that will create something like :

```
login?wrongPass=true.jsp   Which is totally wrong ...
```

now, what is your solution to solve this problem (without) adding that String to model inside our controller & fetch the parameter inside JSP ?
I want the browser url become something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/login.jsp?wrongPass=true
```

Comment: Please tell me you're not actually doing plaintext password comparisons.

Comment: no I'm not actually doing it in real world, this is just a code which i wote just here, my point is something different & you'll understand it if you read the question till its end.
this bunch of code is just to seize that point & make reader direction straight to the point fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the redirect prefix and then you can use absolute URL

```
return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/myProject/login.jsp?wrongPass=true";
```

You can build the absolute url dynamically also using the methods of HttpServletRequest